# What does the inverse of a graph look like?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I wonder, if given a graph $A$ represented by an adjacency matrix $C$ and one would invert $C$, is there a proof that shows what the structure of $A^{-1}$ would look like? For example looking at the structure of Molecules using the Hückel matrix.

Comment: It would have been nice to see some examples that you come up with.

Comment: There are results on tree graphs. You can find them from the book "Spectra of graphs" by R.B. Bapat.

Comment: When you go for inverse of a matrix, each entries of the inverse matrix may not be always positive. So, some special cases are considered.